# ASP.NET MVC 4 URL or routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 to create a website. In the route.config file I have the following

```
 defaults: new { controller = "announcement", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

So when I type the URL as `localhost` or `localhost/announcement` it works well and the index action is called right. However, when I type `localhost/announcement/index` which also should work I'm getting some JavaScript and jQuery errors.

I'm guessing when I type the word index such script is not recognized for some reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.js"></script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/cufon.js")"></script>`.

Comment: @Ritesh works like a charm with the js files. but didn't work with the flash file, any idea? Thanks

Comment: See you have set the path relative to index, so browser makes the url as .../index/js/cufon.js. And web server does not find *js* dir in *index* dir. `Url.Content` creates a url relative to your site root. Alternatively, you can use `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cufon.js"></script>`. Notice */* in path. It access site root and you can use this path for your flash file as well.

Comment: @Ritesh thats really helpful, but still didn't make it work with the flash. I have the flash as  <embed src="/slideshow.swf" style="width: 1003px; height: 440px"> and without the "index" in the URL it works. once I put "index" it says "Load Fail" inside the div of that flash.

Comment: @user3778153 if you try to use "index" MVC think you try to call controller's method (in case if you use default routings). Please provide how should look like your url with flash?